# There is a double new line in this code, how to remove it

Tags: python-3.x

Pardon my ignorance. I've just got started with python. See the following code

```
values = []

print('Enter 10 integers:')

for i in range(10):
    n = int( input('Enter integer %d: ' % (i+1) ) )
    values += [ n ] 
    
print('Creating a histogram from values:')
print('Elements       Values  Histogram')

for i in range( len(values) ):
    print('%8d %12d  ' % (i,values[i]),end='' )
    for j in range( values[i] ):
        print('*',end='')
    print('\n')
```

Between each line of data, there is a new line which I don't know where it comes from in my code. If I delete `print('\n')`, the output is missed up. If I keep it, an empty line between each row appears in the output. Any suggestions?

Without `print('\n')', the output is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use just `print()`. It automatically adds a newline for you when there is no string in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print an empty line after each string, you can add \n to the end of it before the closing example print(\n).but  while print('') (or print()) will only print the newline. when Your question is unclear. print(' ') will print a space character and a newline